# How to figure out the most torrented TV shows by country?

Tags: video, web-scraping, bittorrent

Anyone have any suggestions/starters on how to figure out, for example:
-Most torrented TV show in India over past week?
or
-Most torrented movies in France over the past month?

Basically - want to see most torrented shows/movies by country, over x time period.

Was thinking of using public bit torrent trackers, but don't have much insight on how to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Join any public tracker and sort the shows by "snatches"